# How to swipe to view maintaining navigation bar items?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement the swipe to view functionality just like Twitter's Moments:

[image]

If you take a look at the top you'll see a horizontal slider with the views. My requirement is tad bit different... On top of that horizontal slider I need my regular navigation bar with each page's custom items.

The swipe to view I implemented with some minor errors. Please take a look at this video (this is what I've done so far):

http://sendvid.com/5j50p73z

As you can see the swipe views functionality is working but I'm still missing some important things, namely:

1. When swiping to the next view it is scrolling up (seen on video)
2. My views are all contained in navigation controllers with their respective navbar items. The way I see it I'd need something like `PushViewController` without the back button but that would work both directions... I'm kinda lost here If I add the navigation controller instead of the view it shows the bar, but below the current existing one, not substituting it.

Any ideas on how to solve these?

I'm developing using Xamarin.iOS, but if you can provide an example using swift I guess I could try to translate that :)

This is what I have so far:

```
var viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("detailClaimViewController") as DetailClaimViewController;

viewController.ClaimId = ClaimId;
AddChildViewController(viewController);
ScrollView.AddSubview(viewController.View);
viewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);

var sumsInsController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("sumsInsuredListViewController") 
                                  as SumsInsuredListViewController;
var sumsInsuredFrame = sumsInsController.View.Frame;

sumsInsuredFrame.X = View.Frame.Size.Width;
sumsInsController.View.Frame = sumsInsuredFrame;
sumsInsController.ClaimId = ClaimId;
sumsInsController.Title = $"Sums insured for {Title}";

AddChildViewController(sumsInsController);
ScrollView.AddSubview(sumsInsController.View);
sumsInsController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);


ScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Frame.Size.Width * 2, View.Frame.Size.Height - 49);
```

This is the code I "need" to work, because it loads the navigation bar and that `ViewController`'s custom navbar items (as I said this one "works" but it shows the correct navigation bar below the standard one, it doesn't substitute it):

```
var viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("detailClaimViewController") as DetailClaimViewController;

viewController.ClaimId = ClaimId;
AddChildViewController(viewController);
ScrollView.AddSubview(viewController.View);
viewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);

var navController = new UINavigationController();
var sumsInsController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("sumsInsuredListViewController") 
                                  as SumsInsuredListViewController;
var sumsInsuredFrame = sumsInsController.View.Frame;

sumsInsuredFrame.X = View.Frame.Size.Width;
sumsInsController.View.Frame = sumsInsuredFrame;

sumsInsController.ClaimId = ClaimId;
sumsInsController.Title = $"Sums insured for {Title}";
navController.AddChildViewController(sumsInsController);

AddChildViewController(navController);
ScrollView.AddSubview(navController.View);
navController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);


ScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Frame.Size.Width * 2, View.Frame.Size.Height - 49);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation items are defined per contained view controller within a `UINavigationController`. You can work around that in different ways, but my recommendation would be to use a custom `UIViewController` that acts as the container for the other `UIViewController`s you want to present.

For example, you could build a custom `UIViewController` that contains your custom navigation bar and a view for the content itself, to act as a custom `UINavigationController`. With custom transitions, you can mimic the behaviour of the original class.

Please refer to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) for a better explanation on container view controllers.

Comment: Gianluca, thank you for your answer. Would you care to expand on that? Perhaps with an example? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the answer isn't very clear… I'll edit… give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into that. I'll mark it as answer as soon as I'm able to implement it. Thanks for now :)